# expected } got success error found

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
myClickHandler = function(e) {
       var ng = $('#num_groups').val();
       for (var group = 1; group <= ng; group++) {
         if (!validation(group)) return false;
       }
       if (confirm( "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n")) {
         $.ajax({
           url: "insertpenaltymarks.php",
           data: $("#PenaltyMarks").serialize(),
           async: false,
           type: "POST"
           success:function(result){
            $.ajax({
                 url: "sessioncomplete.php",
                 async: false,
                 type: "POST",
                 success:function(response){
                      window.location = "complete.php";
                  }
               });
        }
         });
         return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

With the above code I am trying to send 2 ajax requests, one to go to `insertpenaltymarks.php` page and the other to go to the `sessioncomplete.php` and `complete.php` page. But I am getting an error I don't really quite understand:

```
Syntax error at line 57 while loading: expected '}', got 'success'
           success:function(res
```

What does this error actually mean and how can it be fixeD?

Comment: Syntax errors should be fixed by examining your code and/or running it through a validation checker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set comma after `"POST"` in the first Ajax call:

```
// ---------v
type: "POST",
success: function(result) {
```

Comment: I always wonder, how possible that people post such problems. Isn't it faster to find it just reading error message + using IDE..

Answer (score 0):

You need a comma after `"POST"`.